# Deriviative of Triangular Moving Average

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, time-series

Maths is not my strong point and I would like to know the formula to the first derivative of a triangular moving average.

The source formula can be found here http://blastchart.com/Community/IndicatorGuide/Overlays/TriangularMovingAverage.aspx

If you could present it in a non math expert way that would be greatly appreciated! May be even a worked example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear for me what "the derivative of a moving average" means. Derivative with respect of... what? A moving average is not a function, but an operator (or, if you prefer, a filter).

Comment: A reference answer can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51642/use-calculus-to-calculate-the-slope-of-a-moving-average-line however, instead of a Simple Moving Average I need to use a Triangular moving average. Hope that helps.