# The derivative of a moving L2 norm

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

Consider the class of $C^0$ signals $x(t)$ such that
$$
\left|x\left(t+T\right)-x\left(t\right)\right|\leq\epsilon 
$$
I would like to find a uniform bound on the derivative of its moving rms, which is defined by
$$
J\left(t\right)=\left(\frac{1}{T}\int_{t-T}^{t}\left|x\left(\tau\right)\right|^{p}d\tau\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
with $p=2$. Apparently, when $\epsilon=0$, $J$ is always constant and the derivative is uniformly 0; so I wonder whether $
\left|\frac{dJ}{dt}\right|
$ is uniformly small when $\epsilon$ is small.

It might be worth noting that a uniform bound could be found when $p=1$ (in the case of moving average), see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57307.

It would also be interesting to find out whether it holds for other $p\in[1,\infty]$.

Answer (score 1):

I will consider the case $p=2$ and (for convenience) the slightly different RMS definition
$$
J(t) = \left(\frac{1}{T}\int_{t-T}^t|x(\tau)|^2 d\tau\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Let $K(t)\triangleq J^2(t)$. Assuming that $x(t)$ is continuous, it follows from the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) that
$$
\frac{dK}{dt} = \frac{1}{T}\left(|x(t)|^2-|x(t-T)|^2 \right)
$$
Since it also holds $\frac{dK}{dT}=2J\frac{dJ}{dt}$, we have an explicit expression for the derivative of $J(t)$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dJ}{dt}&=\frac{1}{2TJ(t)}\left(|x(t)|^2-|x(t-T)|^2 \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2TJ(t)}\left(|x(t)|-|x(t-T)| \right) \left(|x(t)|+|x(t+T)| \right)
\end{align}
$$
Taking the absolute value on both sides and recalling that $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$, a bound for the magnitude of the derivative can be obtained as
$$
\left|\frac{dJ}{dt}\right| \leq \frac{|x(t)|+|x(t-T)| }{2T} \frac{|x(t)-x(t+T)|}{|J(t)|}
$$
Noting that

- The first ratio of the RHS is bounded (continuity of $x(t)$),
- $J(t)\geq \frac{1}{T}\int_{t-T}^{t}|x(\tau)|d\tau$ (power means inequality, see, e.g., [[The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](https://books.google.gr/books/about/The_Cauchy_Schwarz_Master_Class.html?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&redir_esc=y), Ch. 8, pp. 127-128]) with the RHS tending to a constant as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$,

it follows that 
$$
\left|\frac{dJ}{dt}\right| \rightarrow 0
$$
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, implying that $\left|\frac{dJ}{dt}\right|$ is small when $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: The above hold under the assumption $J(t)\neq 0$. However, $J(t)=0$ if and only if $x(t)=0$ for all $t$ (continuous $x(t)$), which is a case of no practical interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! However, I have a few questions. **Firstly**, I am a bit worried about the power means inequality. For most references I find it seems that it only applies to finite-dimensional vector space, and I wonder whether it can be readily extended to the function space here. **Also**, I am also concerned about the last bit under the special case where J(t)=0. Is it possible to formalise this part? **Lastly**, do you think this can be extended to other p cases? I am not sure whether the 'difference of two squares' step can be generalised.

Comment: @Alan I have edited the answer to address your first two questions. Regarding extension to all $p$, I would expect it does hold, proved along the same lines (or using induction).

Comment: I've been thinking about your answer and why I feel there's something wrong. Now I think I've finally realised it: I actually mean a uniform bound for a class of signals that satisfy the condition, rather than a bound for a given signal that satisfies the condition (see the modified question). So, in this case, will a uniform bound still exist?

Comment: @Alan By "uniform bound" you mean a bound that applies to all functions within the specified class of signals? I don't see why the answer does not imply a uniform bound since an arbitrary function within this class is considered in the derivation (no extra assumptions than the ones defining the class). Of course, I may be wrong...

Comment: Yes I do mean uniformly for all functions within this class. I feel that I might be able to find a counterexample for this. I will write it down in my answer and we can discuss about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a counterexample for such a uniform bound to exist. Consider the following sequence of functions: 
$$
x_{k}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\epsilon n\cos\left(\omega_{k}t\right) & t\in\left[2\pi n+\pi-\frac{\pi}{2\omega_{k}},2\pi n+\pi+\frac{\pi}{2\omega_{k}}\right]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $k$ is the index, $\omega_{k}=k$ and $n\left(t\right)$ is a step function which increments its value upon every cycle of $T=2\pi$. The graph of each function essentially looks like a bunch of pinnacles rising above the level plane with increasing magnitude. As the index $k$ grows, the pinnacles become thinner. It can be shown that 
$$
\left\Vert x_{k}\left(t+T\right)-x_{k}\left(t\right)\right\Vert _{\infty}=\epsilon
$$
for all $t\geq0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$. However, the derivative grows unbounded as $k\rightarrow\infty$. The figure below shows the $k=1$ and $k=5$ cases. 
[image: k=1][image: k=5]

This result may not be that surprising from @Stelios's answer, noting the fact that 
$$
\frac{dJ}{dt}=\frac{1}{2TJ(t)}\left(|x(t)|-|x(t-T)|\right)\left(|x(t)|+|x(t+T)|\right)
$$
In this particular counterexample, the value of $\frac{1}{2T}$, $\left(|x(t)|-|x(t-T)|\right)$ and $\left(|x(t)|+|x(t+T)|\right)$ are the same at corresponding peaks, but the value $J(t)$ at these peaks tend to zero as $k$ grows, so the derivative also goes unbounded. Therefore, sorry about asking this question, but I think there may not be a uniform bound unless further assumptions are imposed (something to do with how spread-out the functions are).

Comment: @Stelios Maybe you can help me check this one.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was not notified automatically. The issue with your argument is that you have not considered the behavior at the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, since, in that case, the numerator of $dJ/dT$ also tends to zero. In addition, the function $x_k(t)$ tends to the zero function as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ (for any $k$). I would expect a function that is non identically zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for a counterexample.

Comment: @Stelios I agree with part of what you say. Indeed, for each $x_k(t)$, $dJ/dt$ tends to zero as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. However, what the example says is that for any $\epsilon>0$ (no matter how small it is), the bound $dJ/dt$ for each $x_k(t)$ would be different and tends to infinity as $k$ tends to infinity. Therefore, there is no uniform bound.

Comment: What is the behavior of $dJ/dt$ with $p=1$ (moving average) for this class of functions? I believe that $dJ/dt$ also becomes unbounded as $k \rightarrow \infty$ (for any $\epsilon >0$). Does this behavior contradict the statement in your post that "a uniform bound could be found when $p=1$ (when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$)"?

Comment: @Stelios That's what intrigues me. Interestingly, a uniform bound does exist for all such functions when $p=1$, and a **closed-form** bound can be given as $\epsilon/T$. The simulation also confirms this with this very sequence of functions.

Comment: Interesting, I would expect otherwise as $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k(t)$ is a "train of increasing impulses", i.e., of the form $\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(t-l2\pi)$, (with $\int_t \delta(t)dt=1$) with the support of the moving average containing only a single impulse, therefore, resulting in a "staircase" moving average with "jumps" observed at the times when the sliding window "moves" to the next impulse. Anyway, you might want to try asking the [signal processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) for some input.

Comment: I am not too sure about the limit case, but I think the impulse-train function is excluded from the class of functions under consideration anyway since it's not continuous anymore. However, for any given arbitrarily large (but finite) $k$, the same bound holds (when $p=1$). On the contrary, when $p=2$, this bound keeps increasing.